# How can I format a time to HHMM with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to get the hour and minute in 24 hour HHMM format so that 1:01 would be 0101

I figured out a way to do it for the month and year but can't find a way for the hour and minute.

Here is what I have so far.

```
set whichUrl to 0
set fileNames to "map"
set theStartDate to the date "Tuesday, June 21, 2016 at 00:00:00"
set theEndDate to theStartDate + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365) --1 year
set theDate to theStartDate

repeat until theDate = theEndDate
        set theURL to "http://site.com/map.php?iso="

        set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to (theDate)
        set theModDate to (y * 10000 + m * 100 + d) as string

        set theURL to theURL & theModDate & hours of theDate
        set theURL to theURL & minutes of theDate

        tell application "Safari"
            activate
            set the URL of document 1 to theURL as text
            delay 2

        end tell
    set theDate to theDate + (600) --advance 10 minutes
    set whichUrl to whichUrl + 1
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script that takes the current time and makes it HHMM as you asked.

```
-- preserve the current text item delimiters so we can put them back
set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters

set right_now to current date
set the_time to time string of right_now -- something like "4:20:56 PM"
set am_pm to characters -2 thru -1 of the_time as string -- is it AM or PM

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
set the_hour to text item 1 of the_time as string -- in this example, "4"
set the_minute to text item 2 of the_time as string -- in this example, "20"

if (am_pm is "PM") then
    set the_hour to the_hour + 12
end if

if the_hour is "24" then
    set the_hour to "12"
end if
-- that could have been more graceful but it's nice and obvious this way

if (count of the_hour) is 1 then -- padding with a zero if necessary
    set the_hour to "0" & the_hour
end if

if (count of the_minute) is 1 then -- padding with a zero if necessary
    set the_minute to "0" & the_minute
end if

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set steves_string to the_hour & the_minute as string -- putting the pieces together

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims -- cleaning up

return steves_string -- you would not need this line, but for testing it's nice
```

I am sure that this could be tightened up but I thought it was educational to see it step by step.

You could certainly pass in any time you wanted-- does not have to be "current date." (Note that current date includes the time too. You peel off the "time" part of a date by asking for "the time string" of it.

Comment: Thanks Christian! I ended up finding some other code and incorporating it. It works fine just as I'm sure yours would.

Answer (score 0):

```
set whichUrl to 0
set theStartDate to the date "Tuesday, June 21, 2016 at 00:00:00"
set theEndDate to theStartDate + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365) --365 normally
set theDate to theStartDate

repeat until theDate ≥ theEndDate
    if whichUrl ≥ 19997 and whichUrl ≤ 40000 then --In case I just want a range.
        set theURL to "http://siteaddress?iso="

        set theModDate to theDate

        set theModDate to theModDate as date
        set D to characters -2 through -1 of ("0" & theModDate's day) as text
        copy theModDate to tempDate
        set the month of tempDate to January
        set M to characters -2 thru -1 of ("0" & 1 + (theModDate - tempDate + 1314864) div 2629728) as text
        set Y to characters -1 thru -4 of ((year of theModDate) as text) as text
        set hh to "0" & theModDate's hours as text
        set hh to characters ((count of hh) - 1) through (count of hh) of hh
        set mm to "0" & theModDate's minutes as text
        set mm to characters ((count of mm) - 1) through (count of mm) of mm
        set ss to "0" & theModDate's seconds as text
        set ss to characters ((count of ss) - 1) through (count of ss) of ss
        set theDateTxt to (Y & M & D & "T" & hh & mm as text)
        set theURL to theURL & theDateTxt
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
        do shell script "curl -o ~/test/test.php." & theDateTxt & ".jpg 'http://siteaddress?iso='" & theDateTxt
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    end if
    set theDate to theDate + (900) --seconds (1800 is 30 minutes)
    set whichUrl to whichUrl + 1
end repeat
```